# How to put a string inside a std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a vector of char that its all elements are initialized by '-' like this:

```
 vector <char> vec (10, '-'); //vec = "----------"
```

consider we have two inputs: a string and an integer representing the starting index. for example:

```
 string word = "HELLO";
 int start = 3;
```

I Want to put `word` inside the vector `vec` starting from the index `start` so that after this operation, `vec` should be like this:

```
 //vec = "---HELLO--"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), vec.begin() + start);
```

Comment: Just make sure that `vec.begin() + (start + word.size())` does not exceed `vec.end()` or else the copy will write past the capacity of the vector, causing undefined behavior.